# NVIDIA GeForce FX 5200 Proprietary Driver Problem

Tags: nvidia

So i am attempting to install the proprietary driver for the FX 5200 & I keep getting this error message:

```
ERROR: Installation has failed. Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details. You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com."
```

So I checked the and was still confused to what the problem was:

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Tue Sep 20 17:04:26 2016
installer version: 1.0.7

PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

option status:
  license pre-accepted               : false
  update                             : false
  force update                       : false
  expert                             : false
  uninstall                          : false
  driver info                        : false
  precompiled interfaces             : true
  no ncurses color                   : false
  query latest version               : false
  OpenGL header files                : true
  no questions                       : false
  silent                             : false
  no recursion                       : false
  no backup                          : false
  kernel module only                 : false
  sanity                             : false
  add this kernel                    : false
  no runlevel check                  : false
  no network                         : false
  no ABI note                        : false
  no RPMs                            : false
  no kernel module                   : false
  force SELinux                      : default
  no X server check                  : false
  no cc version check                : false
  run distro scripts                 : true
  no nouveau check                   : false
  run nvidia-xconfig                 : false
  sigwinch work around               : true
  force tls                          : (not specified)
  X install prefix                   : (not specified)
  X library install path             : (not specified)
  X module install path              : (not specified)
  OpenGL install prefix              : (not specified)
  OpenGL install libdir              : (not specified)
  utility install prefix             : (not specified)
  utility install libdir             : (not specified)
  installer prefix                   : (not specified)
  doc install prefix                 : (not specified)
  kernel name                        : (not specified)
  kernel include path                : (not specified)
  kernel source path                 : (not specified)
  kernel output path                 : (not specified)
  kernel install path                : (not specified)
  precompiled kernel interfaces path : (not specified)
  precompiled kernel interfaces url  : (not specified)
  proc mount point                   : /proc
  ui                                 : (not specified)
  tmpdir                             : /tmp
  ftp mirror                         : ftp://download.nvidia.com
  RPM file list                      : (not specified)
  selinux chcon type                 : (not specified)
```

Using: `nvidia-installer ncurses user interface`

```
-> The file '/tmp/.X0-lock' exists and appears to contain the process ID '781'
   of a runnning X server.
ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before installing. 
       For further details, please see the section INSTALLING THE NVIDIA DRIVER
       in the README available on the Linux driver download page at
       www.nvidia.com.
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file
       '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find suggestions
       on fixing installation problems in the README available on the Linux
       driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

And also my computer hardware info:

```
    description: Mini Tower Computer
    product: OptiPlex GX260
    vendor: Dell Computer Corporation
    serial: CM2PT21
    width: 32 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.3 dmi-2.3 smp-1.4 smp
    configuration: administrator_password=enabled boot=normal chassis=mini-tower cpus=1 power-on_password=enabled uuid=44454C4C-4D00-1032-8050-C3C04F543231
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 00T606
       vendor: Dell Computer Corp.
       physical id: 0
       serial: ..CN6986133V0C51.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Dell Computer Corporation
          physical id: 0
          version: A09
          date: 11/01/2004
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 448KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect edd int13floppytoshiba int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb agp ls120boot biosbootspecification netboot
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.26GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 400
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 15.2.7
          slot: Microprocessor
          size: 2266MHz
          capacity: 3060MHz
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 533MHz
          capabilities: boot fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe pebs bts cid xtpr
          configuration: id=0
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 700
             size: 8KiB
             capacity: 16KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back data
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 701
             size: 512KiB
             capacity: 512KiB
             capabilities: internal varies unified
             configuration: level=2
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 1000
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 1GiB
          capacity: 1GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM SDRAM Synchronous 266 MHz (3.8 ns)
             physical id: 0
             slot: DIMM_A
             size: 512MiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 266MHz (3.8ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM SDRAM Synchronous 266 MHz (3.8 ns)
             physical id: 1
             slot: DIMM_B
             size: 512MiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 266MHz (3.8ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE/PE DRAM Controller/Host-Hub Interface
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 01
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=agpgart-intel
          resources: irq:0 memory:e0000000-efffffff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE/PE Host-to-AGP Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master
             resources: memory:fc000000-fdffffff memory:f0000000-f7ffffff
           *-display UNCLAIMED
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: NV34 [GeForce FX 5200]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 66MHz
                capabilities: pm agp agp-3.0 vga_controller cap_list
                configuration: latency=64 maxlatency=1 mingnt=5
                resources: memory:fc000000-fcffffff memory:f0000000-f7ffffff memory:fd000000-fd01ffff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:16 ioport:ff80(size=32)
           *-usbhost
                product: UHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-38-generic uhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.1
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:19 ioport:ff60(size=32)
           *-usbhost
                product: UHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-38-generic uhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Mouse
                   product: Dynex 5-Button Wired Optical Mouse
                   vendor: Primax Electronics, Ltd
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: usb@3:2
                   version: 1.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=2Mbit/s
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.2
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:18 ioport:ff40(size=32)
           *-usbhost
                product: UHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-38-generic uhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@4
                logical name: usb4
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             product: 82801DB/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-M) USB2 EHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.7
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:fe300800-fe300bff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-38-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Wireless interface
                   product: SAMSUNG_Android
                   vendor: SAMSUNG
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 99.99
                   serial: 47900aebffe0d000
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=rndis_host maxpower=2mA speed=480Mbit/s
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: 81
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master
             resources: ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:fe100000-fe2fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: c
                bus info: pci@0000:02:0c.0
                logical name: enp2s12
                version: 02
                serial: 00:0b:db:63:ec:21
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 66MHz
                capabilities: pm pcix msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI latency=64 link=no mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair
                resources: irq:18 memory:fe1e0000-fe1fffff ioport:ecc0(size=64)
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: 82801DB/DBL (ICH4/ICH4-L) LPC Interface Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: 82801DB (ICH4) IDE Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.1
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ide bus_master
             configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=0
             resources: irq:18 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:ffa0(size=16) memory:c0000000-c00003ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: ioport:dc80(size=32)
        *-multimedia
             description: Multimedia audio controller
             product: 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.5
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_intel8x0 latency=0
             resources: irq:17 ioport:d800(size=256) ioport:dc40(size=64) memory:fe300400-fe3005ff memory:fe300000-fe3000ff
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: ST3100011A
             vendor: Seagate
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 3.02
             serial: 4LH0B85H
             size: 93GiB (100GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=f699ccdf
           *-volume:0
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: a05b0ac0-6fc5-4eff-8bdd-4fac6204a8f7
                size: 92GiB
                capacity: 92GiB
                capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2016-09-17 16:43:44 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2016-09-20 17:06:09 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2016-09-20 17:06:20 state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: Extended partition
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                size: 1021MiB
                capacity: 1021MiB
                capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume
                   description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
                   physical id: 5
                   logical name: /dev/sda5
                   capacity: 1021MiB
                   capabilities: nofs
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD reader
             product: RW/DVD GCC-4482B
             vendor: HL-DT-ST
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: 1.00
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp0s29f7u1
       serial: 06:a0:a9:49:a6:8f
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.243 link=yes multicast=yes -
```

Comment: Are you using the installer from the website?

Comment: Yes. I did use the installer from the NVIDIA's website.

Comment: Well, it says: "ERROR: You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before installing."

Comment: *facepalm* Oh yeah, thats definitely the problem, but any clue on how to fix it though.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the installer from the website. It requires you to kill the X server (the GUI basically) and run everything from the terminal. You also need to uninstall `nouveau` (the generic driver for NVIDIA on Ubuntu), which is a pain.

Instead, it's better to just open the **Additional Drivers** app and select one of the proprietary options there. For more choices, add this PPA:

```
ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

(options for this will show up as `open-source`, although they are not)

For more details: [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

Comment: How do I add the ppa? (sorry I just recently install Ubuntu)

Comment: I'm only getting one driver and its for my Pentium 4 (which i've already installed). - Update: since my graphics card is an FX 5200 it looks like that it only supports the GeForce 6-8 line of cards.

Comment: You're expecting too much of a more than a decade old entry level Dell Optiplex - Optiplex is the professional (office) line and on top of it GX260 always was the cheapest entry level model - and an equally old Nvidia Graphics. Please check the current system requirements for WoW (native Windows): https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/world-of-warcraft-system-requirements

Answer (score 0):

FX 5200 is very old and no longer supported in the newer Nvidia drivers. According to Nvidia the support ended after version 177. This version is no longer available either at Ubuntu's main repository or at the recommended PPA in another answer.

Given the old age of that hardware there's really no point in installing proprietary drivers. The open source `nouveau` already in use is enough to make it work the best it can with a current Linux OS.

Comment: Well, the main reason I wanted the proprietary driver is for Wine to play World of Warcraft because the standard driver didn't seem to support 3D applications.

Comment: You're not playing WoW on a GX260 by any means.